# An inequality for sums

Tags: calculus, inequality, summation

If I have two non-negative series $f(k)$ and $g(k)$ such that
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}f(k)\leq \sum_{k=1}^{n+1}g(k),\tag1$$
Does this imply that

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(k)\leq \sum_{k=1}^{n}g(k)\tag2$$

> I have tried to prove it as follows
> $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(k)\leq \sum_{k=1}^{n+1}f(k)\leq \sum_{k=1}^{n+1}g(k)\nleq
> \sum_{k=1}^{n}g(k)$$
> which don't give (2) !!

Any alternative proof or counterexample to this question is very appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to MSE!

Consider

- $f(1) = 1$, $f(2) = 1000000$
- $g(1) = 10$, $g(2) = 0$

Then $\sum_{k=1}^1 f \leq \sum_{k=1}^1 g$, but
$\sum_{k=1}^2 f \not \leq \sum_{k=1}^2 g$.

Can you see how to find a similar example for larger $n$?

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Helps very much ^_^

Comment: Glad to hear it ^_^. If it answered your question you should mark it as such so that other users know how to spend their time.

Comment: I already marked it, my bro

Comment: You've upvoted it (which I appreciate too), but to mark an answer as accepted you have to click the checkmark underneath the up/downvote arrows. Of course, there's no pressure to accept if you want to wait for other answers.

Answer (score 2):

$f(k)=0$ for $2 \leq k \leq n$, $f(1)=1$, $g(k)=0$ for $1 \leq k \leq n$, $f(n+1)=0, g(n+1)=2$ is a counter-example.